# How to procect API from man in the middle attacks

Tags: api, security

I will build a cross platform application (WP8, IOS, Android) and those apps will use
my server to make API requests.

My server also will call different type of APIs (google, facebook, etc) and return some results. 
And application owner does not has to be logged in to make those calls.

If there is man in the middle, he can track api calls and use it for his own usage drain my quota against api services I am using.

I only want phone who has application be able to make those calls.
What would be the best way to detect api calls to my server should come from my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SSL to prevent man in the middle attacks but there really isn't a way that you can be 100% certain that you are communicating with your application.. You can make it harder to do by requiring some sort of access token or using custom encryption but if somebody can decompile your app they can do whatever they want.

Comment: hmm, you mean even IOS apps can be reverse-engineered and my private key for my encryption can be stolen from my source code?

Comment: Yes. The apps are not encrypted when they are uploaded to the App store, neither are they encrypted when they are downloaded to the end device. It would technically be possible for iOS to do so using something like RSA's asymmetrical encryption if Apple stored the private key(s) on some sort of internal smart card (like a SIM card) or some other internal secure device, but as seen with the PS3's key leak, extreme knowledge and attention to detail is required and nothing is as secure as you think it is.

Comment: A jailbroken iPhone will be able to circumvent smart card encryption by using it to decrypt the app anyways, without even having to know the key. That's probably the reason apps aren't evcrypted in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

In your specific case you should use HTTPS and in the client, not only check that you are using an HTTPS connection, but that the certificate presented by the server and its certificate chain are the ones you expect.
If you fail to do so, you could still perform a MITM attack. For example:

- The MITM proxy could act as the client to the server and use an HTTP connection to serve the contents to the real client.
- The MITM proxy could act as the client to the server and use a self-signed SSL certificate to present the real client an HTTPS connection.